# Matlab: 'hold on' doesn't work with 'set()'?

Tags: matlab, plot, set

I am plotting multiple plots on the same axes by using `plot()` and `hold(Ax, 'on')` function. However, I have noticed that if I use `set(Ax, 'XData', ..., 'YData', ...)` for plotting instead of `plot()` then the `hold(Ax, 'on')` functionality does not work. In other words I am not able to plot all the curves together on same axes if I use `set()` function. Any idea why is that, or if there is a way by which I can use `set()` and yet use the `hold on` functionality? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this explanation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/312462).

Comment: Yes, I did look at it earlier. However, I could not quite get the suggestion there..

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why can't/won't you use `plot`?

Comment: I am using `brush` to select the data from the plot.The script for brushing the data requires the `XData` and `YData` which can be stored through `set(Ax, 'XData', ..., 'YData', ...)`. I am not sure if `plot()` allows to do that as I have not been able to figure that out yet..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/312462), you can try something like the following example:

```
x1 = linspace(1,10,21);
y1 = rand(1,21);

x2 = x1;
y2 = rand(1,21);

x3 = x2;
y3 = rand(1,21);

h(1) = plot(x1,y1,'b');

h(2) = copyobj(h(1),gca); 
h(3) = copyobj(h(1),gca); 

set(h(2),'XData',x2,'YData',y2,'Color','r')
set(h(3),'XData',x3,'YData',y3,'Color','g')
```

The [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) command updates the properties of the object referenced by the handle. If you don't want to modify your one curve over and over, but add curves, you have to copy the initial line object, using [`copyobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html). Once you do that, you can generate an infinite amount of additional lines for which you can then set the properties (including new `'XData'`, `'YData'` as you please.
However, you will need an initial line object to copy and modify.
Also, depending on how you set up your plot, consider replacing `gca` by your axis handle so that the reference is correct.