# Recreate plot in MATLAB using figure handle

Tags: matlab, graph, charts

Is there anyway to create the same plot twice by saving it to some type of axis handle?

My plotting code creates special symbols for each point in a scatter plot.  I want to create a figure with two subplots.  The first plot I want set for a specific part of the axis (0 to 10), the second plot I want to be from (90:100).  I know I could recreate the plot by copy and pasting my code, but this seems cumbersome and a hassle to manage if I change something else about my plots.

Is there anyway I can just create my plot once, save it to a handle and then replot it?

Here is basically the functionality I am looking for:

```
figure;
hold on;
x = [1  10 20 10   2000 3000];
y = [10 30 40 20   100   200 ];

// Create plot one point at a time     
for i = 1:4
subplot(2,1,1); plot(x(i),y(i),'r');

// REDACTED CODE
// There is a bunch of code here to adjust the look of the first plot for each point
// In order to define the look of each marker in a scatter plot, 
// this has to be done one point at a time
// REDACTED CODE

end

// Adjust axis
axis([1 60 0 50]);

// Get figure handle
handle = gcf;


// Create second plot with same characteristics as first plot but with different axis boundaries
subplot(2,1,2); plot(handle);
axis([90 250 1000 4000]);
```

Comment: How about creating a function that takes the range as an input and generates the plot? That's a good way to avoid copying and pasting code.

Comment: I could do that, but then I would have to create a function each time I want this plot. I just want some generic solution I can use for any subplot I plan on creating.

Comment: Do you mean only using the function `plot` one time?

Comment: I don't understand. You just call the same function with a different input every time you want the plot in a different subplot.

Comment: I just updated the question so you can see what I mean. Please take a look at the code I wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can turn that code into a function:

```
function makeAPlot(axBound, ax)
% set current axis
axes(ax)

hold on;
x = [1  10 20 10   2000 3000];
y = [10 30 40 20   100   200 ];

for i = 1:4
 plot(x(i),y(i),'r');

% // REDACTED CODE
% // There is a bunch of code here to adjust the look of the first plot for each point
% // In order to define the look of each marker in a scatter plot,
% // this has to be done one point at a time
% // REDACTED CODE

end

axis(axBound)
```

And here's how you can call it twice with differnt arguments to plot it in different subplots with different axes ranges:

```
ax1 = subplot(2,1,1);
makeAPlot([1 60 0 50], ax1)

ax2 = subplot(2,1,2);
makeAPlot([90 250 1000 4000], ax2)
```

If that doesn't work, you could look into the `copyobj`function  and use it to copy the handle to the plot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer however, this is for a specific plot. I need a generic solution that doesn't require making a new function for different datasets

Comment: Add your dataset as an input to the function. Functions generally are the generic solution. If it really won't work, see my edit and try the copyobj function.

Comment: Hmm, do you have an example of how to use the copyobj function?

Comment: @starbox [I do in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366214/matlab-hold-on-doesnt-work-with-set/17366998#17366998)